# Min Order date within last 24months from list of orders related to Account Object

Tags: trigger, business-logic

I have a date field on the Account object and the date field is called "New_Cust_date_for_cellsep_in_last_24mnth__c". Account object has orders related to them. The Orders object is called "VM_Sales_Order__c". I am now trying to get the least date from within last 24months on which an order had been places from the list of orders related to accounts object.

Can someone help me how to write the logic for this scenario. 
Below is my code:

```
trigger MINcellsepInvoiceDate_24mths on Account (before update) {

Set <Id> AccId = new Set <Id>();
List <VM_Sales_Order__c> Orderlist = new List <VM_Sales_Order__c>();
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
//datetime myDateTime = datetime.now() -750;
date myDate = date.today() - 730;
date myDateCURRENT = date.today();
system.debug('myDate  '+myDate );
//2014-09-27 00:00:00
//date dt = System.today()- 750;

for(Account Acc:Trigger.new){
AccId.Add(Acc.Id);
}

Orderlist = [Select Id, Name, Order_Date__c from VM_Sales_Order__c WHERE Customer_Account__c = :AccId AND Order_Date__c < :myDate and Order_Date__c > :myDate ORDER BY Order_Date__c DESC];
//Orderlist = [Select Id, Name, Order_Date__c from VM_Sales_Order__c WHERE Customer_Account__c = :AccId AND Order_Date__c!=NULL AND Order_Date__c < :myDate ORDER BY Order_Date__c ASC limit 1];
//System.debug('Size of Orderlist' + Orderlist.size() );
//System.debug('Size of ONE' + Orderlist[1] );
//System.debug('Size of Order Date' + Orderlist[1].Order_Date__c);
for(Account acc2:Trigger.new)
{
if(!Orderlist.isEmpty())
{
acc2.MIN_CellSep_Invoice_Date_Last_24_mth_2__c=Orderlist[0].Order_Date__c;
//acc2.Phone_Extension__c='test';
//accList.add(acc2);
}
}
//update accList;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: put the code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: @harvey I posted an answer, take a look at it and lemme know if I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have covered 2 scenarios

1) After an order record is inserted, the trigger will update the date on account to the created date of the first created order. Update to an order will not hurt the created date so we do not have to worry on update triggers.

2) After an order is deleted the trigger will update the date to the next oldest order record's date on the account. Before deleting an order the order is still associated with the account and so we do not care about before update triggers.

3) When you undelete an order, you are out of luck since,The after undelete trigger event only fires for the following objects:

- Account
- Asset
- Campaign
- Case
- Contact
- ContentDocument
- Contract
- Custom objects
- Event
- Lead
- Opportunity
- Product
- Solution
- Task

---

Trigger code:

```
trigger minimumDateOrderTrigger on VM_Sales_Order__c  (after insert, after delete)
{
List<Id> accountIdList = new List<Id>();
List<account> accountstoupdate = new List<account>();

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isDelete) {  

            //Trigger.new is not null in insert scenario. 
            if(Trigger.new !=null){
                for(VM_Sales_Order__c  order:trigger.new){
                    accountIdList.add(order.accountId);
                }   
            } 

            //trigger.old is not null in a delete scenario.
            else{
                for(VM_Sales_Order__c ord:trigger.old){
                    accountIdList.add(ord.accountId);
                }
            }

        //check for the plural name of the VM sales order object and append an __r. Read more about relationship queries to understand the __r concept. I have assumed the pulral name of the object would be VM Sales Orders.
        for(Account acc :[SELECT    id,New_Cust_date_for_cellsep_in_last_24mnth__c,
                                    (select id,createddate from VM_Sales_Orders__r where createddate> LAST_N_MONTHS:24 ORDER BY Createddate ASC LIMIT 1)
                         FROM       Account
                         WHERE      Id IN: accountIdList]){

            //If there are orders associated to an account then pick the created date and update.
            if(acc.VM_Sales_Orders__r.size()>0){
                for(VM_Sales_Order__c ord: acc.VM_Sales_Orders__r){

                    //Get the created date of the first VM_Sales_Order__c on the account.
                    acc.New_Cust_date_for_cellsep_in_last_24mnth__c = ord.createddate;
                    accountstoupdate.add(acc);
                }
            }

            //If there are no contact associated then enddate = null. This can happen when you delete the last contact related to an account. (or) when there is no contact associated to the account.
            else{       
                    acc.New_Cust_date_for_cellsep_in_last_24mnth__c = null;
                    accountstoupdate.add(acc);
            }
        }

        if(accountstoupdate.size()>0){
            update accountstoupdate;
        }

    }

}
```